# linux-image-generic error

Tags: package-management, kernel

My ubuntu 16.04 will give me the result that

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-70-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-signed-image-4.4.0-70-generic
 linux-signed-image-generic
 linux-signed-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

whenever and whatever I install, what should I do?

Comment: Show us the entire error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels

it can solve the problem ,which maybe due to lack of storage.